# Haml - End caching explicitly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have _product.html.haml file with caching:

```
- cache product do
  %tr{product_id: "#{product.id}"}
    %td.col-md-1.vert-align= image_tag product.image.url(:thumb), class: "img-thumbnail" if product.image?
    %td.col-md-4.vert-align= link_to product.title, product
    %td.col-md-1.vert-align= number_to_currency product.price
    %td.col-md-1.vert-align= product.available ? content_tag(:span, 'Available', class: "available") : content_tag(:span, 'Booked', class: "booked")

    - if user_signed_in? && current_user.is_admin
      %td.col-md-2.vert-align
        = link_to "Edit", edit_product_path(product), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs"
        = link_to "Delete", '#', title: "Delete product", class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-product"
```

I don't need to cache if block at the bottom. How cache do/end block can be ended explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to cache the whole `<tr>` if you want to have a non-cached `<td>` inside it.

You can cache the 4 `<td>`s instead:

```
%tr{product_id: "#{product.id}"}
  - cache product do
    %td.col-md-1.vert-align= image_tag product.image.url(:thumb), class: "img-thumbnail" if product.image?
    %td.col-md-4.vert-align= link_to product.title, product
    %td.col-md-1.vert-align= number_to_currency product.price
    %td.col-md-1.vert-align= product.available ? content_tag(:span, 'Available', class: "available") : content_tag(:span, 'Booked', class: "booked")

  - if user_signed_in? && current_user.is_admin
    %td.col-md-2.vert-align
      = link_to "Edit", edit_product_path(product), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs"
      = link_to "Delete", '#', title: "Delete product", class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-product"
```